# Is npm request asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, node-request

I can't understand Javascript asynchronous behavior.

I always thought that 'request' module would be synchronous. I used it , though, in my code, and something went absolutely wrong.

An example:

```
download_page = function(item) {
    page = request.get( { url: 'http://test-fdfdfd.com/' + String(item) })
}
node = new App();
node.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready.");
    Array.from(Array(3).keys()).forEach(item => download_page(item));
    node.stop()
})
```

In that code, node should stop only after the three requests were completed. However, that didn't happen and I don't know why.

Could someone give me an explanation?

Comment: What about the [`request` documentation](https://github.com/request/request/blob/master/README.md) led you to believe that the module would be synchronous in the first place?

Comment: `request()` is ALWAYS asynchronous.  Always.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[request](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request) is actually asynchronous.

You might want to return a `Promise` from your function, and then `Promise.all` all of them.

```
download_page = function(item) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        request.get( { url: 'http://test-fdfdfd.com/' + String(item) }, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
                return;
            }
            resolve(data);
        });
    });
}
node = new App();
node.on('ready', () => {
    console.log("Ready.");
    Promise.all(Array.from(Array(3).keys()).map(item => download_page(item)));
    node.stop()
})
```